# Get `(typeof TheClass)['prototype']` with a `&` type intersection

Tags: typescript

I need to extract the type from a class, which can demonstrate by the following code:

```
abstract class Test {}

/**
 * Basic
 */
type TOK = typeof Test
type TOKP = TOK['prototype']
// TOKP = Test

/**
 * With Constructor()
 */
type Constructor<T> = new(...args: any[]) => T
type TNO = typeof Test & Constructor<Test>
type TNOP = TNO['prototype']
// TNOP = any
// Question: how to make TNOP as the type `Test` instead of `any`?
```

In `Basic` section, the `TOKP` is `Test`, which is right.
In `With Constructor()` section, the `TNOP` is `any`, the typing is lost.

My question is: if I have to use the `typeof Test & Constructor<Test>`, how can I prevent the type of `TNOP` to be `any`? I want it to be `Test`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that a constructor is considered a `Function`, whose interface is defined in the standard library [`lib.es5.d.ts`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.8.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L288) to have a `prototype: any` property.

---

There are multiple ways to do what you want.  One is to modify your `Constructor<T>` definition to:

```
type Constructor<T> = { new(...args: any[]): T, prototype: T };
type TNOP = TNO['prototype']; // Test
```

---

If you can't do that and you are using TypeScript v2.8 or later, you can use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) (specifically, [type inference in conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types)) to extract the instance type of a constructor whether or not the `prototype` is set the way you expect:

```
type InstanceType<T extends new(...args: any[]) => any> = 
  T extends new (...args: any[]) => infer U ? U : never

type TNOP = InstanceType<TNO>; // Test
```

---

There might be other solutions (e.g., modifying your local copy of `lib.es5.d.ts` to add more type safety to `Function['prototype']`), but hopefully one of those will help you.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer save my life!